# Save worksheet as PDF on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, pdf

I am working on a macro to save the active sheet as a PDF file with a special name.
The macro I created runs but saves every sheet in several PDF and puts the name of the sheet at the end of the file name.

```
Sub PrintPDF() 
    Dim wksSheet As Worksheet 
    Dim strFile As String 

    Set wksSheet = ActiveSheet 
    'strFile = Format(Now(), "yyyymm") _
                & ".pdf" 

    strFile = "blabla" _ 
                & "_" _ 
                & Format(Now(), "yyyymm") _ 
                & "_" _ 
                & "name2" _ 
                & " " _ 
                & Replace(Replace(wksSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value, " ", ""), ".", "_") _ 
                & ".pdf" 

    strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & ":" & strFile 

    wksSheet.SaveAs Filename:=strFile, FileFormat:=xlPDF 
End Sub
```

Comment: just a thought. try adding 'IgnorePrintAreas:=True' in your save line.

Comment: Please provide an example of what the output is.

Answer (score 0):

You have discovered a bug in Excel Mac 2011 VBA!

Despite using your syntax of `ActiveSheet.SaveAs` or my preferred:-

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFile, FileFormat:=xlPDF, PublishOption:=xlSheet
```

Excel Mac 2011 VBA will always save all worksheets.

If you turn on the Macro Recorder and save a sheet to PDF, it works as expected and writes out the `ActiveWorkbook` version to the code module.  Now immediately re-run that very code that it generated and it yields a different result!

I can confirm that this bug does not exist in Excel Mac 2016 and that the worksheet syntax is no longer supported.  You will need to change to the workbook syntax I included above.

Comment: Actually, I still run into that same bug in Excel Mac 2016 (workbook syntax as you describe but exports the whole workbook). PublishOption:=xlSelected does not help either. With other FileFormat values, PublishOption is well taken into account, so the bug definitely resides in the xlPDF Format converter. Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The following method solves the problem

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strFile
```